# Can Dropbox Djinni be used with C++98

Tags: c++, cross-platform, dropbox, c++98, djinni

I am trying to evaluate Djinni, for generating Java and Obj-C wrappers from our C++ code.
We currently use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) and are evaluating other tools for wrapper generation.

Due to some restriction at my work place our C++ code is in C++-98.
We cannot migrate to C++-11 due to some customer needs.

As such I wanted to know if I can use **Djinni**, with C++-98.
[Djinni github](https://github.com/dropbox/djinni) readme states:

> Interfaces are objects with defined methods to call (in C++, passed by shared_ptr). Djinni produces code allowing an interface implemented in C++ to be transparently used from ObjC or Java, and vice versa.

I saw couple of sample's using Djinni over the internet and they all seem to use `shared_ptr`s with their interfaces.
Is C++-11 mandatory for using Djinni?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Djinni can not be used with C++98. It uses C++11 pretty extensively, both in the generated code and in the support library, so it can't support C++98.